# inheritence how to return the subclass object?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, inheritance

```
    Base Class B
    |
    |
    ----
    |   |
    |   |
    D1  D2

public static object GetDerivedClass(Type t1, MyProcess p1)
{
     DerivedClass D1 = null;
     DerivedClass D2 = null;

     if (t1 is typeof(Derived)
     {
            Process(D1,p1);
            return D1;
     }
     else if(t1 is typeof(Derived)
     {
            Process(D2,p1);
            return D2;
     }
}
```

My Question is what will be the generic way to return the type of object which is passed as t1 Type,

because in real implementation I have deep hierarchy of my design pattern with lots of D1,D2,etc...

Comment: Confused... in the diagram is D1 / D2 a *type*? or (per the C# example) a *variable*? And what signatures of Process are there?

Comment: I think the diagram represents a class hierarchy...

Comment: My point is that it doesn't tally **at all** with the code example...

Comment: Sure... sample is pretty obscure ;o) That was just my two cents...

Comment: Question is simple, I have suppose 3 Derived class of base and according the the parameter Type passed in the function I want to return that type of instance but for that I have to take 3 local Derived class variables, so far if I have 10 such Types I have to delcare 10 DerivedClass variables in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-write your `Process` method as a generic method, i.e.

```
T Process<T>(MyProcess p1) where T : new
{

    // do work
    // apparently your Process method must be creating a new instance
    // this is why I put the new constraint on the type parameter
    T t = new T();

    // set properties of t, etc.

    return t;
}
```

Your `GetDerivedClass` method is now redundant.  Simply call the `Process` method as follows:-

```
var obj = Process<MyDerivedType>(p1);
```